# Подключение к SQL SERVER через vba и другого пользователя windows

Tags: sql, авторизация, vba

У меня есть задача - сделать универсальный импорт данных из экселя в бд sql, средствами vba.

Основная проблема в том, чтобы загружать данные могли любые пользователи независимо от их прав доступа к базам.
Самих хранилищ около 10, но на каждом из них есть виндовый пользователь домена xx\Loader, у которого есть права write на таблицы.

Идея состоит в том, что бы при соединении с сервером, использовать виндовый логин xx\Loader, но я не могу найти опцию в строке подключения, которая позволит это сделать. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Устроят также альтернативные варианты решений. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в свою строку подключения значение `SSPI` для свойства `Integrated Security`. В этом случае для аутентификации пользователя используются текущие полномочия учетной записи Windows.

Если же необходима аутентификация под конкретным пользователем, то в этом случае `Integrated Security` должно устанавливаться в `false`. Так же необходимо указать те значения для `User ID` и `Password`, которые требуются для входа.

**Пример**:

```
 "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;PASSWORD=12345;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=TRUE;USER ID=username;INITIAL CATALOG=DBName;DATA SOURCE=Server;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;"
```

Можете почитать [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821690%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) или [неплохой туториал](http://www.askit.ru/custom/vba_office/m9/09_03_ado_connection.htm).

Comment: В том то и дело, что мне не нужна авторизация под своей учетной записью. Мне нужна авторизация под конкретной учеткой - xx\Loader.

Comment: @T.Zagidullin, обновил ответ

Comment: Если речь идет об аутентификации под конкретным виндовым пользователем, то Integrated Security=false не поможет. Я нашел ответ здесь http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66014/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-in-a-different-domain. Если коротко, то  это невозможно. Альтернатива запускаться от имени другого пользователя с помощью /runas

Comment: Я привёл рабочий пример Connection String для VBA и SQL Server. При чём тут вообще виндовый пользователь, если на сервере уже есть нужная учётка?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Если правильно понял вопрос:</sub>

Используйте в макросе подключение:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
login = ...
pass = ...
conn.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=" & pass & ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & login & ";Data Source=..."
```

Для выполнения запроса используйте:

```
conn.BeginTrans
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
...
createTable = "create table test (id integer, name varchar(256))"
cmd.CommandText = createTable
cmd.Execute
```

Не забудьте через Tools -> References в окне макроса добавить "OLE Automation".